# cloning git repository on thumbdrive

Tags: git, clone

I already have a local workig space repository in /applications/mamp/htdocs/myproject/.git and i can't figure out how to clone it onto a folder in my thumbdrive and use that as my remote to push to.

do i have to create a bare git repository in the directory on my folder first? and then clone my working space one to it?

or do i just cd into my directory on my thumbdrive(with no .git directory) and clone the working space repo to it which would automatically create the .git repo on the thumbdrive?

i'm confused on the proper steps to use my thumbdrive as my remote repo

my thumbdrive's path is "volumes/thumbdrive/"

now i'm trying to add my remote but i can't seem to get the path right i guess...

```
David-Adamss-MacBook-Pro:myproject davidadams$ git remote add flashstick /volumes/thumbdrive/repo/.git
David-Adamss-MacBook-Pro:myproject davidadams$ git remote
flashstick
thumdrive
David-Adamss-MacBook-Pro:myproject davidadams$ git push flashstick master
fatal: '/volumes/thumbdrive/repo/.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

and this didn't work either

```
David-Adamss-MacBook-Pro:myproject davidadams$ git remote add flashdrive /volumes/thumbdrive/repo
David-Adamss-MacBook-Pro:myproject davidadams$ git remote
flashdrive
flashstick
thumdrive
David-Adamss-MacBook-Pro:myproject davidadams$ git push flashdrive master
fatal: '/volumes/thumbdrive/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
David-Adamss-MacBook-Pro:myproject davidadams$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone the local repository into your `volumes/thumbdrive` and then setup remotes to this newly cloned repo from the old one

```
`git remote add thumbdrive volumes/thumbdrive`
```

The remote name after above would be `thumbdrive` ( use origin if you want ) and you can push like

```
`git push thumbdrive master`
```

Another approach:

Copy / move `/applications/mamp/htdocs/myproject/.git` to the thumbdrive and then clone it back to the desired location.

Comment: maybe cloning isn't what i want. I would also like a working copy on my thumbdrive. Cloning doesn't provide that, does it?

Comment: @David Cloning does provide working copy. Only when you do a bare ( --bare ) does it not create a working copy.

Comment: ok, so to clone it...do i have to "git init" the directory in my thumbdrive first? from which would i issue the clone commande: "/volumes/thumbdrive/repo" or "/volumes/thumbdrive/repo/.git?

Comment: @David No in thumbdrive you would do `git clone /applications/mamp/htdocs/myproject/ .` No `git init`

Comment: ok, i just did this from 'volume/thumbdrive/repo': "git clone /applications/mamp/htdocs/myproject/.git" and it said "cloning into myproject..." did i just overwrite my repo in /applications/mamp/htdocs/myproject/.git?

Comment: @David - no it would have created `myproject` dir in `volume/thumbdrive/repo` - Also note the `.` in the end of my clone statement. It would have created it in the `repo` folder itself if you had done that.

Comment: ok, yeah i just checked and everything is working and it created that directory on my thumbdrive. Now i having trouble setting it up as a remote to push to. i have this now(i think) "/volumes/thumbdrive/repo/.git". when im adding a remote do i use that path or this "/volumes/thumbdrive/repo" or "volumes/thumbdrive/repo"(no slash in front of volumes)?

Comment: * i say "i think" because i can't see the hidden .git directory and am hoping it's there

Comment: if you look back up at my original question, i edited what i tried and found didn't work

Comment: @David - you are not doing the `git remote add` properly. You are just giving the name, but not the path to the repo. Follow my answer.

Comment: i did, for some reason it didn't get copied in there, i fixed the original post to show what i've tried with no avail

Comment: @David - Shouldn't it be `git remote add flashdrive /volumes/thumbdrive/repo/myproject`

Comment: i think i just cloned the working copy onto my flashdrive with no repository...I can't "cd /volumes/thumbdrive/repo/.git". Says there's no directory there *frustrated*

Comment: @David - it cloned into `/volumes/thumbdrive/repo/myproject`

Comment: @David let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/996/discussion-between-manojlds-and-david)

Comment: oh you're definitely right about adding myproject to the end of it...but alas i get another error *see original question

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to cd to /volumes/thumbdrive/repo directory and then:

```
git clone --bare /applications/mamp/htdocs/myproject/
```

This will clone the repo, but won't make any working copies on the thumbdrive. If you look at the remote, you'll see one directory created, called myproject.git, which is probably what you want.

Then from your local git repo:

```
git remote add thumbdrive /volumes/thumbdrive/repo/myproject.git
```

After you make changes, you can:

```
git push thumbdrive master
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `volumes/thumbdrive/`, then:

```
git clone /applications/mamp/htdocs/myproject/
```

From then on, you can just `push` things to `volumes/thumbdrive`, or pull from `/applications`